# where to get the screen unlocked sound

Tags: android

I want to use the sound when we unlock screen for my app, I prefer to use something from system than put that sound file to raw. Where to get it ? 
(I think it maybe in android.R... but not found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the source code from [here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), you can find it at `frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/Unlock.ogg`.

I uploaded the file [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?fzjzui21s67v223), if you need it quickly (this link will probably go dead eventually).

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar and this helped me a lot: 
[How to unlock your unlock/lock sound](http://droidpirate.com/2010/08/23/how-to-change-your-unlocklock-sound/).

You just have to access the root directory and find the .ogg file. Just save the file after that, it's pretty straightforward.